# Preview colours in Emacs-ESS

Tags: emacs, r, colors, preview

I accidentally managed to get colour names, #HEX, and a colour preview in Emacs. Don't have a bloody idea how, must've pressed some keybinding or menu item... But, now I can't seem to find where's that feature... I'm quite sure I wasn't hallucinating, so it's gotta be there, under some keystroke that I can't reproduce!!! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, what is your question? :)

What you've described can be reproduced by `M-x list-colors-display` (or Control-click with middle mouse button, then select display colors from the pop-up menu) -- and it's an Emacs feature, nothing to do with R or ESS.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that was just the thing I've been looking for. As far as I know, R has 657 preset colours (`http://research.stowers−institute.org/efg/R/Color/Chart`), and Emacs displays 546. I hope they are R-compatible... quick glance at colour names made me think so... =)
Thanks lad!

Answer (score 2):

If/when you find yourself in that situation, where something happened in Emacs, but you don't know how.  You can ask Emacs what the last 300 keys you pressed were with <kbd>C-h l</kbd> (which is bound to [`'view-lossage`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-Help.html), and that might give you enough information as to what you did.

Comment: A couple of related tips: C-h a gives you an apropos help search (e.g. if you just did C-h a "colors" you would've found the function).  Also, an M-x enhancement like that provided by ido mode or smex (possibly also anything.el or icicles) (look for any/all of the above on emacswiki) allows you to do M-x "stuff" and lists commands that contain the word "stuff" -- very handy.